# Is the set of projections of elements on a given orbit also an orbit?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a set which is invariant under the action of a Lie group $G$. Suppose that $y \notin \mathcal{S}$ and that $x^\star \in \arg \min_{x \in \mathcal{S}} \| y - x \|$. Is it true in general that $\arg \min_{x \in \mathcal{S}} \| y' - x \| \cap G x^\star \neq \emptyset$ for all $y' \in G y$? In other words, does every element on the $G$-orbit of $y$ have a projection onto $\mathcal{S}$ lying on the orbit of a projection of $y$ onto $\mathcal{S}?$